# Beginner Question: How can I update my commits?

Tags: git, git-bash

In my GitBash, I edited the commits until there's only four left.

[image: Image 1]

That is because I want to like update what's on our website and get rid of those other two about me files.

[image: Image 2]

I tried to directly push it, but it it says this.

[image: Image 3]

Is there a quick way to do it?

Comment: Try running `git pull`

Comment: @mousetail No. Why would OP pull the commits they explicitly want to get rid of?

Comment: Then `git fetch`, then git will let you force push

Comment: The push is rejected because the new history doesn't match the remote one. If local history has to replace it, the push command just lacks a `--force-with-lease` option and it will succeed. (**Be sure to double-check your new history first, though, as this cannot be undone.**)

Comment: @mousetail it just says that "Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.". I can't seem to find a step by step in the internet that is related to mine. They only work on their situation.

Comment: Run `git merge --abort`

Comment: @RomainValeri Hello. What are the necessary steps should I do?

Comment: Okay thank you, I run it and in the git status doesn't show the error anymore. @mousetail

Comment: @naomi Vincent's answer details what I suggested. Go for it, it should be fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind+its+remote+counterpart+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you effectively rewrote history, git will not allow you to simply push the new truth. You will need what is called a "force push", described here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---no-force-with-lease.

Please note that `git push --force-with-lease origin master` means all checks are skipped, and you may therefor lose commits. In this case though, that seems to be what you are intending to do (removing a few commits) so it's OK.

**Please make double and triple sure that you're pushing exactly what you want to push. If you don't have a copy of the repository elsewhere, then this might be a tricky thing to revert.**

Also, do not use `--force-with-lease` with every push, only when you really need to.

Comment: We do not know if OP is working alone on the repo or not, but the cautious `--force-with-lease` variant of `--force` can't do harm. Good answer here.

Comment: Yes, this worked. I first made sure that what's on my local repository commits are the ones I really wanted to overwrite. I then did git push --force origin master. It overwrites which is what I intended. 10/10 thank you @Vincent!